# compare 2 arrays eg. csv

Tags: windows, shell

i would like to know if it is possible to compare 2 list via shell. The setup:

List "`A`" with about 6000 entries 
List "`B`" with about 300 entries

Is it possible to detect wich are duplicate and wich are unique in "`B`"? Is there a way to save those in an extra file?

Thanks

Comment: i can save them in both formats. csv with only 1 column or txt

Answer (score 0):

If (as I assume) you want to compare two ASCII / Text files, you can use FC:

```
FC.exe

Compare the contents of two files or sets of files. Display any lines which do NOT match.

Syntax
      FC /B pathname1 pathname2

      FC [options] pathname1 pathname2

Key
   /B  : Perform a binary comparison.

options
   /C  : Do a case insensitive string comparison

   /A  : Displays only first and last lines for each set of differences.

   /U  : Compare files as UNICODE text files.
   /L  : Compares files as ASCII text. (default)

   /N  : Display line numbers (ASCII only)

   /LBn: Limit the number of lines that will be read, "n" sets a maximum number
         of consecutive differing lines after which the File Comparison will abort (resync failed)
         When FC aborts then "n" number of mismatches will be shown.
         default=100 lines.

  /nnnn  : Specify a number of consecutive lines that must match after a mismatch.
           This can be used to prevent the display of the two files from getting 
           too out of sync

  /T     : Do not expand tabs to spaces.
  /W     : Compress white space (tabs and spaces) for comparison.

To compare sets of files, use wildcards in pathname1 and pathname2 parameters.

Powershell also has an Alias FC for the Format-Custom cmdlet, therefore to run the 'old' FC under powershell you need to explicitly run C:\windows\system32\fc.exe

To identify 2 identical files use this syntax:

   FC file1.txt file2.txt | FIND "FC: no dif" > nul 
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :s_files_are_different
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the shell. What commands do I need to get only the duplicated lines?

Comment: This is not possible with this simple tool, you only can to save the output in the new file. Try fc /N file1.txt file2.txt > comp.txt

Comment: i played around and I only get errors: (translated) _Resynchronization failed. Files are too different._ I think it's because of the large line differences.

Comment: I have tried as well, it works fine ... I'm sorry for you! :(

Comment: What? You asked for an answer with Shell, and then your comment is you don't know how to use Shell?? Or did I miss something?

Comment: It's formulated a bit hard. I was watching to an alternative to my slow comparison program witch took (i feel so) hours to compare. My idea was to use the super fast shell instead. I hoped it were a bit easier and more funktionally.

Comment: Take a look at WinMerge, it's free: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/files/stable/